# LinkedIn Follow Button - viewport change on android 2.2 & 2.3 when button is loaded

Tags: android, webview, linkedin-api, viewport

I have problem with LinkedIn Follow Button. I am developing responsive website for mobile devices. I am using this meta for android browsers:

```
<meta content='True' name='HandheldFriendly' />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width = device-width, height = 0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

On old android devices (2.2 & 2.3) (on ipad, galaxy tab, iphone and new android devices it is ok) when content and javascripts are loaded everything seems to be ok. After I load the following srcipts:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="myid" data-counter="right"></script>
```

white space of around 200x200px emerges to the right of the follow button and device.vieport().width changes causing webview to be scrollable. The funny thing is that even if I place the button in hidden and absolutely positioned container the viewport is still being changed.

Does anyone had the same problem or found solution to it?